# gestureRecognizer shouldReceive touch not called in Mac catalyst

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uipangesturerecognizer, mac-catalyst

> 1. I have 2 Pan gestures one on child view and other on parent view I want
>    to prevent one gesture recogniser based on condition. I have
>    implemented logic using shouldReceiveTouch delegate method and it is
>    working fine. but shouldReceiveTouch method is not called in Mac
>    catalyst due to which my logic failing in Mac catalyst.  What is
>    alternate to this method or how to make sure this method gets called
>    in Mac catalyst as well.
> 2. below is my code.

```
 extension AMCollectionInCollectionViewCell {
    public override func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        guard let view = touch.view?.superview else { return false }
        return view.isKind(of: UICollectionReusableView.self)
    }
}
```